# SugarORM offset not working

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'm using SugarORM for my Android app. I want to load messages from the SQLite DB but need an offset.

So I load message 5-15 like for pagination.

Unfortunately the offset function doesn't seem to work as expected.
I wrote:

```
query = Select.from(Message.class)
     .where(Condition.prop("MESSAGES").eq(Long.toString(getId())))
                        .orderBy("timestamp DESC")
                        .limit("5")
                        .offset("10");
query.list();
```

But this only gives me the limit of 5 elements but doesn't use any offset.

Same if I parameterize the query call like this:

```
List<Message> messages = getAllMessagesQuery.offset("5").list();
```

Offset isn't working.

Am I doing something wrong? I use the current SugarORM version 1.5

> (    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5')

stating the working offset functionality. So this shouldn't be the issue.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure this is the best way to do but at least it's working this way.
If I add the short version to the limit things work fine.
So using the query like this:

```
List<Message> messages = getAllMessagesQuery.limit("5,10").list();
```

gives me 10 messages with a 5 message offset.

If that is too dirty, a raw query is also working fine. So you write:

```
List<Message> messages = Chat.findWithQuery(Message.class, "Select * from Message where Chat = ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5", getId().toString());
```

Still no idea how to use the offset parameter directly but at least it works this way.